# login don't redirect to admin index page after login in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello guys the below code doesn't work and redirect me to the admin index page . 
Please note that , database connection is established successfully, when i enter the data on the login page , it doesn't direct me to the adminindex page after successful login , instead the page is refreshed to the same page 'test.php', and prints the failure message of 'That information is incorrect'

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && 
isset($_POST['pincode'])) {

$email=$_POST['email'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
$pin=$_POST['pincode'];

include('db_conx.php');


$sql = "SELECT admin_id FROM admin WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass' 
AND pincode='$pin' LIMIT 1";
$query=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);

$line = mysqli_num_rows($query);

 if ($line == 1){ 

     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
         $id = $row['admin_id'];
         }
         $_SESSION['admin_id']=$id;
          $_SESSION['email']=$email;
          $_SESSION['pincode']=$pin;
         header("Location: adminindex.php");
         exit();
 }else {
    echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
    exit();

}
}

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
    <body> 
    <h1>Welcome to Admin page login</h1>
    <br> 
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
        Email:<br />
          <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="40" />
        <br /><br />
        Password:<br />
       <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40" />
    <br>
    <br /><br />
        Pincode :<br />
       <input name="pincode" type="number" id="pincode" size="40" />
    <br>


    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In" />
    </form>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: In your source code, is there any space before the first "<?php" tag? Have you checked your PHP error logs to see if there's any indication of the problem? Have you tried using your web browser's dev tools to see if any messages are being output to the console?

Comment: Print number of rows, i guess its `ZERO`

Comment: As 4EACH noted (and after looking more closely at your query) - it looks like your query should always return just 1 record - the only case it wouldn't of course is if the query is failing or not behaving as you seem to expect it to in this instance.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Parameterize your query. Do not store plain text passwords, hash them.

Comment: Thanks @FillardMillmore ,The query only return on output , in which it should be the right admin based on inputs , still doesn't work , i understand my code is open for SQL injection , however it was meant as a test , as i want to take it further then this , but i can't even pass this stage .

Comment: When you get the output "That information is incorrect" then you query doesn't return one row. For debugging purposes, output the value of `$line` with `var_dump()` to see how many rows have been found.

Comment: Thank you all , i will try my best to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips and help , its all working now .